# Chat Issue: Grant Access for Low Reputation does not Work

Tags: bug, reputation, chat

I would like to discuss with a user lower as 20 with an issue.

In the Access-Control Tab, i can grant someone access with write permissions as it states

> "Even when this room is read-only or **their reputation is too low**, these users will be able to talk in this room."

But i cant add him as it tells me the User needs at least 20 Reputation.

Is this a Bug on the Chat-Site? Or do i do something wrong?!

Comment: TL;DR: only mods can do it, not RO.

Comment: Could you maybe please be more longtext instead of short-term? I am the Owner of the Channel if it would be the Question

Comment: No I won't. If you want to know more click the link.